# Why is it recommended to add nodatacow to a VM image on BTRFS, but using a QCOW2 disk is ok?

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, btrfs, qcow2

As far as I know, it is recommended to disable copy on write for VM images to avoid performance degradation on BTRFS. However, no one recommends against using `qcow2` disk image format, despite being a copy on write disk.

What is the reason behind this? What are the technical differences between BTRFS's CoW and `qcow2` CoW?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because, due to the way btrfs works, non-sequential writes inside of a file can cause a lot of fragmentation and fragmentation generally degrades performance. This is not only true for VM images but also other file types where non-sequential in-file writes happen, such as databases.

I don't know the specifics but I imagine, since QCOW2 is specifically made for non-sequential in-file writes, it's specifically optimised for that purpose ("files" being virtual disks here; same thing really).